# How to pull string from cell in Excel after repeating characters?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell with the following value:

```
5661:GRE:08:NAME
```

I'd like to find an excel formula that can help me extrapolate from this example the following values into separate columns/cells: `5661 GRE 08 NAME`

I have used `LEN`, `MID`, `FIND` in the past but that was only to find a single "delimiter" like `:` in the above example. Not sure how to figure this out to find values when the delimiter repeats several times in a cell.  Would rather try to solve this in formulas than have to use VBA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Text to Columns from the Data Tab:

Step one:  Choose Delimited hit Next

[image]

Step Two: Click other and put `:` in the box.

[image]

From here you can go on to step three, but it is optional.  Step three allows the user to dictate limit format types.

If you do not care that the columns stay as General then click Finish.

[image]

---

If you want a formula then:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,":",REPT(" ",999)),999*(COLUMN(A:A)-1)+1,999))
```

As you drag/copy to the right it will get the next word.

[image]

Comment: But what if the `:` repeats?  I think the question is asking for help dealing with situations like `5661::GRE:08:NAME` and `5661:GRE::::08::NAME` using formulas

Comment: This is great, thanks Scott.  Is there a way to do this when the delimiter is "-".  I've tried to change your TRIM... formula and it's not working for me.

Comment: @dvpetta change the `":"` to `"-"`

Comment: Funny, I try it doesn't work, you mention it, I try it again and now it works!  Thank you!

Comment: @dvpetta please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @dvpetta below the Down arrow under the '5'  Just left of the start of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data in cell A1,
Run the second Macro

Sub text()
Call Extract_Any_Think(Range("a1"), "\w+")
End Sub

```
Option Explicit

Sub Extract_Any_Think(st As Range, Patt$)
  Dim Obj As Object, i%
  Set Obj = CreateObject("Vbscript.RegExp")
  With Obj
   .Pattern = Patt
   .Global = True
  End With
   If Obj.test(st) Then
     For i = 0 To Obj.Execute(st).Count - 1
     st.Offset(, i + 2) = Obj.Execute(st)(i).Value
     Next
   End If
End Sub
```

'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Sub text()
Call Extract_Any_Think(Range("a1"), "\w+")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the box "treat consecutive delimiter as one" while doing text-to-column.

[image]